# Cannot type anything in react native TextInput component

Tags: react-native

I am new to react-native. I am doing a simple salary calculator component for practice. I have two TextInput components, but I can't seem to type anything in them. Here is the code for my component:

```
class SueldoCalc extends Component {
  constructor(props)
  {
     super(props);
  }

 calcSalario()
 {
   console.log("Calculating");
 }

render() 
{
return (
  <View>
      <Text>Entre las horas trabajadas:</Text>
      <TextInput />
      <Text>Entre el rate por hora:</Text>
      <TextInput />
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.calcSalario}>
        <Text>Calcular salario...</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>
);

}

}
```

I tried subscribing to onTextChange events, but nothing. This is so basic, I can't find anything out there. Please help! I am running the app on Android Simulator for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify onTextChange handler then set the state from there. Your `<TextInput />` should have a value property:

```
<TextInput 
    value={this.state.horas}
    onChange={this._onChangeHandler}
/>
```

Comment: Even after adding both properties I still cannot type anything. I did my TextInput like this:

    <TextInput value={this.state.text} onChangeText={(text)=>{this.setState({text:text})}} />

Comment: While the answer is correct, doing this did not solve the problem. I switched from the Android Emulator for Visual Studio to an AVD created with the Android SDK and this solved my problem.

Comment: try adding a style={{height: 40}} to your TextInput

Comment: Could you have a look at this? onChange doesn't work for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61658623/unable-to-type-in-formik-field

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem both in Android and IOS. After I set width and height as the following (be careful both width and height must be set), the problem solved:

```
<TextInput style={{ height: 20, width: 100 }} />
```