# Unable to Type in <Formik> Field

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, formik, yup

```
interface FormValues {
  friendEmail: string;
}

  const initialValues: FormValues = {
    friendEmail: '',
  };

export const Page: React.FunctionComponent<PageProps> = ({
  toggleShowPage,
  showPage,
}) => {

  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
  const validationSchema = emailValidationSchema;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (showPage) return;
    initialValues.friendEmail = '';
  }, [showPage]);

  const [
    createUserRelationMutation,
    {
      data: addingFriendData,
      loading: addingFriendLoading,
      error: addingFriendError,
      called: isMutationCalled,
    },
  ] = useCreateUserRelationMutation({
    onCompleted: (data: any) => {
      showAlert();
    },
  });

  const addFriend = React.useCallback(
    (id: Number) => {
      console.log('Whats the Id', id);
      createUserRelationMutation({
        variables: {
          input: { relatedUserId: id, type: RelationType.Friend, userId: 7 },
        },
      });
    },
    [createUserRelationMutation],
  );

  const getFriendId = React.useCallback(
    (data: any) => {
      //console.log('Email', initialValues.friendEmail);
      if (data) {
        if (data.users.nodes.length == 0) {
          console.log('No user');
          setErrorMessage('User Not Found');
          Alert.alert('User Not Found');
        } else {
          console.log('ID', data.users.nodes[0].id);
          addFriend(Number(data.users.nodes[0].id));
        }
      }
    },
    [addFriend],
    //[friendEmail, addFriend],
  );

  const [loadUsers] = useUsersLazyQuery({
    onCompleted: getFriendId,
    onError: _onLoadUserError,
  });

  const handleSubmitForm = React.useCallback(
    (values: FormValues, helpers: FormikHelpers<FormValues>) => {
      console.log('Submitted');
      loadUsers({
        variables: {
          where: { email: values.friendEmail },
        },
      });
      //setFriendEmail('');
      values.friendEmail = '';
    },
    [loadUsers],
    //[loadUsers, friendEmail]
  );

  if (!addingFriendLoading && isMutationCalled) {
    if (addingFriendData) {
      console.log('Checking');
    }
    if (addingFriendError) {
      console.log('errorFriend', addingFriendError.message);
    }
  }

  return (
    <Modal
      visible={showAddFriendEmailPage}
      animationType="slide"
      transparent={true}>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View style={scaledAddFriendEmailStyles.container}>
          <View style={scaledAddFriendEmailStyles.searchTopContainer}>
            <View style={scaledAddFriendEmailStyles.searchTopTextContainer}>
              <Text
                style={scaledAddFriendEmailStyles.searchCancelDoneText}
                onPress={toggleShowPage}>
                Cancel
              </Text>
              <Text style={scaledAddFriendEmailStyles.searchTopMiddleText}>
                Add Friend by Email
              </Text>
              <Text style={scaledAddFriendEmailStyles.searchCancelDoneText}>
                Done
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={scaledAddFriendEmailStyles.searchFieldContainer}>
              <Formik
                initialValues={initialValues}
                onSubmit={handleSubmitForm}
                validationSchema={validationSchema}>
                {({
                  handleChange,
                  handleBlur,
                  handleSubmit,
                  isSubmitting,
                  values,
                }) => (
                  <View>
                    <View>

                      <Item style={scaledAddFriendEmailStyles.searchField}>
                      <TextInput
                      style={scaledAddFriendEmailStyles.searchText}
                      placeholder="Email"
                      onChangeText={handleChange('friendEmail')}
                      //onChangeText={e => console.log('Workinggg')}
                      onBlur={handleBlur('friendEmail')}
                      value={values.friendEmail}
                      autoCapitalize="none"
                      />
                        {/* <Field
                          component={Input}
                          name='friendEmail'
                          placeholder="Email"
                          //handleChange={handleChange}
                          handleBlur={handleBlur}
                          //onChange={handleChange}                         
                          //onChangeText={handleChange('friendEmail')}
                          //onBlur={handleBlur('friendEmail')}
                          value={values.friendEmail}
                          autoCapitalize="none"
                        /> */}
                      </Item>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                      <Button                        
                        onPress={handleSubmit}>
                        <Text>
                          Add Friend{' '}
                        </Text>
                      </Button>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                )}
              </Formik>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

Why am I unable to write anything inside my Input field? I have tried using `onChange`and `handleChange`both but it doesn't make a difference. Other SO answers suggested that I should remove `value` but examples of Formik usage that I see online suggest otherwise.

I am trying to follow this for my Formik validation:

https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/build-and-validate-forms-in-react-native-using-formik-and-yup-6489e2dff6a2

EDIT: 
I also tried with `setFieldValue`but I still cannot type anything.

```
const initialValues: FormValues = {
  friendEmail: '',
};

export const AddFriendEmailPage: React.FunctionComponent<AddFriendEmailPageProps> = ({
  toggleShowPage,
  showAddFriendEmailPage,
}) => {

  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
  const validationSchema = emailValidationSchema;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (showAddFriendEmailPage) return;
    initialValues.friendEmail = '';
  }, [showAddFriendEmailPage]);

  const _onLoadUserError = React.useCallback((error: ApolloError) => {
    setErrorMessage(error.message);
    Alert.alert('Unable to Add Friend');
  }, []);

  const [
    createUserRelationMutation,
    {
      data: addingFriendData,
      loading: addingFriendLoading,
      error: addingFriendError,
      called: isMutationCalled,
    },
  ] = useCreateUserRelationMutation({
    onCompleted: (data: any) => {
      showAlert();
    },
  });

  const addFriend = React.useCallback(
    (id: Number) => {
      console.log('Whats the Id', id);
      createUserRelationMutation({
        variables: {
          input: { relatedUserId: id, type: RelationType.Friend, userId: 7 },
        },
      });
    },
    [createUserRelationMutation],
  );

  const getFriendId = React.useCallback(
    (data: any) => {
      //console.log('Email', initialValues.friendEmail);
      if (data) {
        if (data.users.nodes.length == 0) {
          console.log('No user');
        } else {
          console.log('ID', data.users.nodes[0].id);
          addFriend(Number(data.users.nodes[0].id));
        }
      }
    },
    [addFriend],
    //[friendEmail, addFriend],
  );

  const [loadUsers] = useUsersLazyQuery({
    onCompleted: getFriendId,
    onError: _onLoadUserError,
  });

  const handleSubmitForm = React.useCallback(
    (values: FormValues, helpers: FormikHelpers<FormValues>) => {
      console.log('Submitted');
      loadUsers({
        variables: {
          where: { email: values.friendEmail },
        },
      });
      //setFriendEmail('');
      values.friendEmail = '';
    },
    [loadUsers],
    //[loadUsers, friendEmail]
  );

  return (
    <Modal
      visible={showPage}
      animationType="slide"
      transparent={true}>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View style={scaledAddFriendEmailStyles.container}>
            <View style={scaledAddFriendEmailStyles.searchFieldContainer}>
              <Formik
                initialValues={initialValues}
                onSubmit={handleSubmitForm}
                validationSchema={validationSchema}>
                {({
                  handleChange,
                  setFieldValue,
                  handleBlur,
                  handleSubmit,
                  isSubmitting,
                  values,
                }) => {
                  const setEmail = (friendEmail: string) => {
                    setFieldValue('friendEmail', friendEmail)
                  }
                return(
                  <View>
                    <View>

                      <Item>
                      <TextInput                     
                      placeholder="Email"
                      onChangeText={setEmail}
                      onBlur={handleBlur('friendEmail')}
                      value={values.friendEmail}
                      autoCapitalize="none"
                      />
                      </Item>
                    </View>
                    <View >
                      <Button
                        onPress={handleSubmit}>
                        <Text >
                          Add Friend{' '}
                        </Text>
                      </Button>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                )}}
              </Formik>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

Comment: `onChange={handleChange}` should work. dont use `handleChange={handleChange}`

Comment: Already tried that but didn't work @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: divide it functionally - move formik/form logic into own component, use `useFormik` inside ... pass `handleSubmitForm` [or `loadUsers`] as prop

Answer (score 1):

Formik's Field component doesn't support React native yet. Check [this github issue](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/guides/react-native) for more details

However you can make use of TextInput in place of field and use it with onChangeText handler

```js
<Formik
    initialValues={initialValues}
    onSubmit={handleSubmitForm}
    validationSchema={validationSchema}>
    {({
      handleChange,
      handleBlur,
      handleSubmit,
      isSubmitting,
      values,
    }) => (
      <View>
        <View>
          <Item style={scaledAddFriendEmailStyles.searchField}>
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Email"
              onChangeText={handleChange('friendEmail')}
              onBlur={handleBlur('friendEmail')}
              value={values.friendEmail}
            />
          </Item>
        </View>
        <View >
          <Button 
          onPress={handleSubmit}
          >
            <Text >
              Add Friend{' '}
            </Text>
          </Button>
        </View>
      </View>
    )}
  </Formik>
```

you can read more about Formik's usage with react-native in its [documentation here](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/guides/react-native)

Comment: I still cannot type anything in this TextField either. Perhaps the issue is somewhere else in the code

Comment: any ideas where it could come from?

Comment: Ohh dear, this is difficult to point out then. Do you have any re-render when you try to type a character. Probably because you define initial value in functional component directly and the reference changes everytime you type a character. Try and move that out of the component and see if you still face issues

Comment: Moving initialValues outside also didn't work. I don't think I am using another explicit render anywhere else. I added the full code above tho

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<Input
  placeholder="Email"
  onChange={e => setFieldValue('friendEmail', e.currentTarget.value)}
  onBlur={handleBlur}
  value={values.friendEmail}
  autoCapitalize="none"
/>
```

Comment: Input doesn't have a name property. Even if I comment it out, I still cannot type anything.

Comment: if you comment out name then handleChange won't work. If you are removing name from the field the just try `onChange={e => setFieldValue('friendEmail', e.currentTarget.value)}`

Comment: This gives me ```Property 'value' does not exist on type 'number'.```. Which is weird because I am not using numbers anywhere...

Comment: Try giving `e` type `any` and if it works then change `any` to type of the event. `onChange={(e: any) => setFieldValue('friendEmail', e.currentTarget.value)}`

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple of issues in your codebase.

1. `onChangeText={handleChange('friendEmail')}`. It will trigger the `handleChange` while rendering the component not when you are actualy typing in the input box.
2. `handleChange` function of `Formik` takes `React.ChangeEvent` instead of value. Check [here](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#handlechange-e-reactchangeeventany--void) . While `onChangeText` of `react-native` provides changed text of the input not event. Check [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onchangetext)

You can use `setFieldValue` function for this case:

```
<Formik
    initialValues={initialValues}
    onSubmit={handleSubmitForm}
    validationSchema={validationSchema}>
    {({
      handleChange,
      handleBlur,
      handleSubmit,
      isSubmitting,
      values,
      setFieldValue
    }) => {
    const setEmail = (email) => {
      setFieldValue('friendEmail', email)
    }
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <Item style={scaledAddFriendEmailStyles.searchField}>
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Email"
              onChangeText={setEmail}
              value={values.friendEmail}
            />
          </Item>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
    }}
  </Formik>
```

Please Note: I've never used `formik` with `react-native`. Just trying to connect the dots.

Comment: It doesn't work for me yet. Maybe the issue is somewhere else. I edited the qs to add my full code. Also, in this way there's no use of passing ```handleChange```into Formik right

Answer (score 0):

Formik now works fine with React Native, but another thing to be aware of is that the `name` in your form control must match the **name of the property** in the schema used by Formik.

For example, if using the following Yup schema:

```
const schema = yup.object({
  personName: yup.string().required('Name required')
});
```

Then the following won't work because the Yup schema (`personName`) and the form control (`nameofPerson`) don't match; the user won't be able to type into the field:

```
<Form.Control
  name="nameOfPerson"
  value={values.personName}
  onChange={handleChange}
  onBlur={handleBlur}
  type="text"
  isValid={!errors.personName && !!touched.personName}
  isInvalid={!!errors.personName && !!touched.personName}
/>
```

To make it work, the `name` should be the same as the Yup property; in this case, `personName`:

```
<Form.Control
  name="personName"
  value={values.personName}
  onChange={handleChange}
  onBlur={handleBlur}
  type="text"
  isValid={!errors.personName && !!touched.personName}
  isInvalid={!!errors.personName && !!touched.personName}
/>
```

This example is using **React-Bootstrap** `Form.Control` but should apply to any manner of creating form controls.